# Estimate column norms of $A$ using a few matrix-vector products?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, signal-processing

Suppose I have an $d\times d$ real-valued matrix $A$. How can I approximate $d$ column norms of $A$ by utilizing a small number of calls to matrix-vector product, $f(x)=Ax$?

There are results$^1$relying on vector-matrix products $g(y)=y'A$ but I can't find anything relevant to matrix-vector product, any tips?

$^1$: $d$ calls to $g(y)$ project columns to a $d$-dimensional subspace, can use JL [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) for random $y$'s or [Rudelson/Vershynin](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/W12/Lecture15Notes.pdf) for crafted $y$'s

Comment: Is $x$ a row vector?

Comment: yes (otherwise dimensions don't work)

Comment: edited to use more standard matrix-vector products